# How to check if AI can hit a target (2d platformer)

Tags: libgdx, jbox2d

Hello i'm working on an AI that seeks a target and shot it with an bullet from distance. The bullet will be effected by the gravitation. My game is a 2D platformer and will be released for android. I'm using box2d for the physics.

How could I check if the target can be hit?

Example: AI can't hit the target because there is an object in the way.

I know I could use a ray from owner to target but the bullet won't fly linear to the target.

Comment: To make sure, that the AI can hit the target you would need to "simulate" the bullets flight path. That could get pretty complex, as objects might be everywhere on the flight path.  
I would suggest to only calculate a simple  "assumption". This also makes the AI more "human-like", as the calculations are not perfekt in all cases.

Comment: So should I use a ray?

Comment: Yea you could try that. If the result isn't as good as desired, you can still optimize it (for example limit the distance or ise some kind of curve instead of a ray etc.)